# Build JSON inline that contains JArray

Tags: c#, json.net

I needs to create a JSON structure like this

```
{
"update": {
    "comment": [
        {
            "add": {
                "body": "Bug has been fixed."
            }
        }
    ]
},
"fields": {
    "assignee": {
        "name": "bob"
    },
    "resolution": {
        "name": "Fixed"
    }
},
"transition": {
    "id": "5"
}
```

And to build this i tried the below code in c#

```
        JObject issue_model = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            update = new
            {
               comment = new JArray
                {
                 //How to add JArray contents here inline    
                }
            },
            fields = new
            {
                resolution = new
                {
                    name = "namem vakye gere"
                }
            },
            transition = new
            {
                id= transition_id
            }
        });
```

But how can we add the JArray contents "add" & "body" parts inline?

Comment: JObject.FromObject isn't expecting you to create  the JArray manually, it's expecting something like a Dictionary which **it** converts to a JArray.

Comment: No i wants to avoid the flow like create model first and build json with that . I am looking for inline build of JSON

Comment: @stuartd So how can i achieve the goal of making JSON here? Needs to define the JArray contents in a separate line and provide to JObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use JArray directly, you create anonymous object arrays within the outer anonymous object which `FromObject` then converts to arrays:

```
string transition_id = "5";

JObject issue_model = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    update = new
    {
       comment = new[] { 
            new {
                add = new { 
                   body = "bug has been fixed" 
                }
            }
        }
     },
     fields = new
     {
         resolution = new { 
             name = "namem vakye gere" 
         }
     },
     transition = new { 
        id = transition_id 
    }
}
);
```

Which outputs this Json:

```
{
  "update": {
    "comment": [
      {
        "add": {
          "body": "bug has been fixed"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "resolution": {
      "name": "namem vakye gere"
    }
  },
  "transition": {
    "id": "5"
  }
}
```